# How to Remove Action option form my web part?

Tags: web-part

On my wiki page i added Business Related web part there is one option "Action" i want to remove this option.How can i do this? Using Jquery? or any other option?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untick this checkbox to hide the toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Great its work.